# Windows 10 Printer Spooler not running at startup

Tags: windows, print-spooler

Whenever I turn my computer on, I have to run the printer troubleshooter to turn on the print spooler. It's simply not running at all. How do I check what services run at startup? (I know how to check APPs at startup but not services like the print spooler.

Answer (score 2):

Look through the possibilities in this article.

[Start Print Spooler](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/fixed-print-spooler-keeps-stopping-on-windows-10)

**Solution #1** Run printer troubleshooter

```
To run the troubleshooter:
Press the Windows key+ X and select Settings.
Type Troubleshoot on the search box and click on Troubleshooting Settings.
Locate and click on the Printer troubleshooter and follow the prompts.
```

**Solution #2:** Make Sure Print Spooler Service is Set to Automatic
This method is also called “Check if Remote Procedure Call services are running.”

```
Many users have reported that Remote Procedure Call (RPC) services can also cause problems with the Print Spooler. You need to ensure that these services are running properly. If the print spooler RPC service isn’t set to automatic, it won’t turn on when Windows starts. Your printer won’t work until you manually start the service.
```

**Solution #3:** Delete Print Spooler Files

```
Sometimes Print Spooler service can keep stopping because of Print Spooler files - too many, pending, or corrupt files. Deleting your print spooler files can clear pending print jobs, or the too many files or solve the corrupt files to resolve the problem.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“.
Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q then press “Enter“.
Type net start spooler then press “Enter“.
The print queue on your Windows should now be cleared.
```

**Alternate (but useful Solution):**

Run DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, it is helpful.
Solution 1 - I do this every day in order to print. 
Solution 2 - I checked the RPC it is set to automatic, and the (finder) was set to manual, I changed it to Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

- Run *Start > Services*
- Find "Print Spooler"
- Verify that its "Startup Type" is Automatic and it's running
- If "Startup Type" is not Automatic:

  - Double-click to get into Properties
  - Set "Startup type" to Automatic
  - Click OK
  - Reboot and check if it's running now

Comment: I did try this, and it didn't work. It's set up as automatic but doesn't seem to 'stick.'